# MVC 5 getting Multiple Models into a single view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Newbie to MVC, using MVC 5 and VS 2013.
Code first from existing database, EF6

**Goal:**
Want to show a listing of all models from the tblModel for an MVP listed in tblMVP

**Below is the current state of the project and the runtime error:**

**Error:**
`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.tblAccount>`' does not contain a definition for '`tblModels`' and no extension method '`tblModels`' accepting a first argument of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.tblAccount>` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Models:**

```
    [Table("tblMVP")]
    public partial class tblMVP
    {

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int AccountID { get; set; }  

        public virtual tblAccount tblAccount { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("tblModel")]
    public partial class tblModel
    {

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int AccountID { get; set; }  

        public virtual tblAccount tblAccount { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("tblAccount")]
    public partial class tblAccount

    {
    public tblAccount()
        {

            tblModels = new HashSet();
            tblMVPs = new HashSet();

        }

        public int ID { get; set; }    

        public virtual ICollection tblModels { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection tblMVPs { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
// GET: MVP
public ActionResult Index()
{
var tblAccounts = db.tblAccounts.Include(t => t.tblModels).Include(t => t.tblMVPs);         
return View(db.tblAccounts.ToList());
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.tblAccount>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblModels.partNumber)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountName)
    </th>

</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tblModels.partNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountName)
    </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: in the top, try `model.First().tblModels.partNumber`. Also, your naming conventions for your db objects is bad and doesn't match standards.

Comment: Tried model.First().tblModels.partNumber and get a similar type error:  'WebApplication2.Models.tblAccount' does not contain a definition for 'first' and no extension method 'first' accepting a first argument of type 'WebApplication2.Models.tblAccount' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do two different things. You have an `IEnumerable<tblAccount>`, which doesn't have properties, it just has a list of `tblAccount`.

So in the top, you're trying to get properties of the `IEnumerable`, but there aren't any.

In the bottom, you're iterating the `IEnumerable`, and getting properties of the `tblAccount`, which you are doing correctly.

So in the top section, you need to get a `tblAccount` from the `IEnumerable` so that you can get properties of it. Below is an example of how you can do it.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.tblAccount>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().tblModels.partNumber)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().AccountName)
    </th>

</tr>
```

Comment: Copied and pasted the above, and the tblAccount properties are accessible, but the tblModels properties aren't accessible, such as tblModels.partNumber or tblModels.AccountID .

Comment: Continuing on from the above comment:

In the tblAccount class, changing the navigation properties from
 public virtual ICollection<tblModel> tblModels { get; set; }  to
 public virtual tblModel tblModels { get; set; } allows access to the properties for tblModels but results in a runtime error of 
tblModel_tblAccount_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'tblModel_tblAccount_Source' in relationship 'tblModel_tblAccount'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this is is the bare essentials version of what worked. For better or worse a direct relationship between the tblModel and tblMVP was created and the model loading in the controller was rearranged.

**Models:**

```
    [Table("tblMVP")]
    public partial class tblMVP
    {
        public tblMVP()
        {
            tblModels = new HashSet();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int AccountID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual tblAccount tblAccount { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection tblModels { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("tblModel")]
    public partial class tblModel
    {        
        [Key]
        public int ModelID { get; set; }

        public int AccountID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string partNumber { get; set; }        

        [StringLength(5000)]
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int? MVPID { get; set; }

        public virtual tblMVP tblMVP { get; set; }

      }  

    [Table("tblAccount")]
    public partial class tblAccount
    {
        public tblAccount()
        {
           tblModels = new HashSet();
           tblMVPs = new HashSet();            
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(150)]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }


        public int? AccountNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection tblModels { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection tblMVPs { get; set; }
    }
```

```
**Controller:**
    // GET: MVP
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var tblModels = db.tblModels.Include(t => t.tblAccount).Include(t => t.tblMVP).ToList();
    return View(tblModels.ToList());
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MDLX_Bootstrap_V5.Models.tblModel>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblAccount.AccountName)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.partNumber)
    </th>

</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{        
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tblAccount.AccountName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.partNumber)
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```